# Question on graph colorings

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

For each $s\ge 1$, I want to find a way to colour the edges of $K_{2s}$ so that the graph contains no red path of length $2$ and no blue $K_{s+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Color a perfect matching with red edges and all other edges with blue.